# ActionListener different variable for each button

Tags: java, arrays, swing, jbutton, actionlistener

I have an array of JButtons, and I want to have each one change the value of their respective counterpart variables in another array, do I need to make a separate listener for each button?

Answer (score 1):

The cleanest approach is the make a separate listener for each button.

However, you could make one listener for all buttons which compares the action event's `getSource()` component with every JButton, and performs according to which one the source equals.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to make a separate listener for each buttons. One listener would do, But you have to query for the source using `getSource()` and accordingly decide your path of action.

If you do implement separate listeners then probably it might be easier to code but it may require extra memory. So it all depends on your requirements.